# Joining tables in sql query for a search

Tags: php, mysql

Alright this is a total mess and I'm so lost right now. I'm trying to have a search for a site in which you can search for a word and it will go through a table called `designs` to search the table through multiple columns for the word. I had that working until I decided that I would like the option to also search for the `username` of another member. in the `design` table, there is a column named `user` in which that matches up with the `id` inside of `users`. I hope that makes sense because I really don't want to have to draw out a table..

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT designs.*, users.* 
FROM designs, users 
WHERE type LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($search1) . "%' 
OR title LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($search1) . "%' 
OR tags LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($search1) . "%' 
OR description LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($search1) . "%' 
OR users.username = " . mysql_real_escape_string($search1) . " 
ORDER BY designs.id 
DESC
");
```

This is what it currently looks like, and `$search1` is what the user is searching.. I want to be able to display any `designs` that a user has made by searching for the `username` of the user after connecting the `designs.user` to `users.id` but it just won't work, any ideas?

ALSO `mysql_error()` gives me the error that "Unknown column 'namehere' in 'where clause'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query for inner join is this, and you have to specify the table name like `designs.<columnname>` to query them.

```
    SELECT designs.*, users.* 
    FROM designs
    INNER JOIN users on users.id = designs.user
    WHERE designs.type LIKE '%<SEARCH TEXT>%' 
    OR desings.title LIKE '%<SEARCH TEXT>%' 
    OR designs.tags LIKE '%<SEARCH TEXT>%' 
    OR designs.description LIKE '%<SEARCH TEXT>%' 
    OR users.username = '<USER ID>' 
    ORDER BY designs.id 
    DESC
```

Simple syntax is

```
INNER JOIN <table name> <alias> ON <first table>.<column name> = <second table>.<column name>
```

#### HUGE Problem is you are using `mysql_*` API, please these method are very vulnerable **Do not USE them**

If you use other API like mysqli or PDO, you dont have to use `mysql_real_escape_string` to make your query safe.

Comment: it is giving me the same error... and I was going to look into changing that stuff after I got it all working p: which may seem a little backwards but I am still learning and I at least know some mysql

Comment: @user1874212, What is the error it is giving you, if you the fields and column name are appropriate the above query should work.

Comment: "Unknown column 'what i searched for' in 'where clause'"

Comment: also maybe i should clarify that `users.username` would be the same as the search text.. the id would be `users.id`

Comment: When you get a that type of error that mean the column name does not matches to the database, Can you verify that? That is your part to do not mine I am afraid.

Comment: well the weird thing is that it shouldnt be searching for a column name.. it is saying that the text i inputed to search for is being tried as a column name and the query cannot find that column.. but it isn't a column it is supposed to be a value.

Comment: It seems you have used my solution, the values should be wrapped using a single quote `'` see the `users.username = '<USER ID>'`????

Comment: oooh wow i feel dumb. thanks~ now the only problem is that it is pulling up the design with a `design.id` of `2` and not a design in which the `design.user` is `2` (the user i am searching for has a `user.id` of `2`)

Comment: no i joined `designs.user` and `users.id` because those two are both numbers which should match up.. im trying to search for the `username` in `users` and from that connect the `users.id` of the `users.username` to the `designs.user` or something along those lines

Comment: AHH just kiding somehting else went wrong, it definitely works now, thank you so much! however, is there a way to specify when i am doing `$row['id']` for it to be the design id? because it won't work..

Comment: @user1874212, Yes you can specify an alias while selecting like `SELECT designs.id as \`designid\` FROM designs`